# Convert django Charfield "\t" to tab

Tags: python, django

I have a django model with a Charfield that contains the unicode escaped string "`\\t`".
What is the easiest way to convert this to a real tab (as in `str("\t")`)?

Comment: It **is** a tab.  Where are you seeing `\t`?

Comment: Whoa, one of my backslashes disappeared. Updated question.

Comment: Where are you seeing `\\t`?  Is this in the database?  In a log?  On the web page?  Where are you seeing this?

Comment: in the debug value for the model field: "unicode: \\t"

Comment: "debug value"?  It's a model field?  Where did this data come from?  How did this data get into the model?  Please provide some information on where this value originated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
"\\t".decode("string_escape")
```

as described [here](http://mentaljetsam.wordpress.com/2007/04/13/unescape-a-python-escaped-string/) in the comments

In Python3 syntax：

```
In [5]: b'\\t'.decode("unicode_escape")
Out[5]: '\t'
```

Comment: This may be needless.  Where did this data originate?  You have have done a `repr()`, `unicode()` or `str()` that was not needed.

Comment: This data comes from a postgresql db that does this cast for me on a character field. I have no control over that, so I need this.