# python, \t works different when passed as argument (in Eclipse)

Tags: string, python-2.7, delimiter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Split string with multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters)
>   [Convert django Charfield “\t” to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730270/convert-django-charfield-t-to-tab)

I have written a python code in Eclipse which takes delimiters as an argument. When I do

```
print "Hello",delimiter, "All".
```

This generates --> `Hello \t All`, whereas if I overwrite the delimiter with `delimiter = '\t'` within the code, I get the right output Hello     All. I wonder what is the difference? I hope this not just the eclipse thing.

Comment: Can you do `print len(delimiter)` for both the one passed in from the command line and the one you overwrite in code

Comment: Good stuff. The problem is that `\t` as fed in from the command line is treated as a string of two characters, `print delimiter` should print `'\\t'`, where if you wanted it to create a tab space it should be a string of one character, thus `len('\t')` print `1` for the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that what is being passed in from the command line is actually a string of length two `"\\t"` and not a tab character. You can do the following to your `delimiter`

```
delimiter.decode("string_escape"))
```

that should convert the string `'\\t'` into `'\t'`. The answer comes from a duplicate questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730270/convert-django-charfield-t-to-tab)

Comment: Yup, I just found that and was going to post it. It worked. Thanks.